# Need help Implementing OpenID connect/ OAuth2 flow using React-native, ADFS 4.0

Tags: react-native, adfs

Can some one guide me how to integrate ADFS authentication using react native. i have used react-native-msal library with below format but no luck.

```js
auth: {
    clientId: 'b86ebe9f-3dde-4ab1-a75c-de7a26e909df',
    authorityBase: 'https://testadfs-uat1.test-group.com/adfs/',
    policies: {
      signInSignUp: 'B2C_1_SignInUp',
      passwordReset: 'B2C_1_PasswordReset',
    },
    // redirectUri: Platform.select({ default: undefined }),
  },
}
```